# Open Workbook based on the value of one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble executing these macros in excel2016. I keep getting run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method.
I need the macro to execute automatically and open a workbook named Gradesheet if cell L3 in worksheet QuickCalc2, has a value equal to T3 or T4.

```
Macro 1
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If QuickCalc2.Range("$L$3").Value = "T3" Or QuickCalc2.Range("$L$3").Value = "T4" Then
    Call Open_Workbook_Dialog
    End If 
   End Sub 
Macro 2 
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Set xl = New Excel.Application
xl.Visible = True

Dim strFileToOpen As Variant

strFileToOpen = xl.GetOpenFilename_(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

If strFileToOpen <> False Then
xl.Workbooks.Open Filename:= strFileToOpen
MsgBox strFileToOpen
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you entering the values `T3` or `T4` manually into L3 or does a formula do the job? If the latter, you are using the wrong event. Then you could use the `Worksheet Calculate` event but you would have to figure out how to change the value so you wouldn't end up in an endless loop. Then, to help you, we would need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the CodeName of your sheet is `QuickCalc2` the event code will fail.  Also, you should check if `L3` changed before running your Sub

Something like

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L3") Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Me.Range("L3").Value
            Case = "T3", "T4"
                Open_Workbook_Dialog
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim strFileToOpen As Variant

    strFileToOpen = xl.GetOpenFilename_(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

    If strFileToOpen <> False Then
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Workbooks.Open(Filename:= strFileToOpen)
        MsgBox strFileToOpen
        ' do stuff with wb
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The name of the worksheet is QuickCalc2. Do you see anything wrong with the open workbook code?

Comment: Re _The name of the worksheet is QuickCalc2_. that's not the same as the CodeName.  To reference the sheet by name you'd use`Worksheets("QuickCalc2")`.  That said, in the worksheet code module, `Me` is better

Comment: Re _Do you see anything wrong with the open workbook code?_ why are you creating a new instance of Excel?  Also, create a workbook variable and assign the newly opened book to that

Comment: I need to create a new instance of excel if the entity being assessed fails the first assessment with a score of t3 or t4. They need to be assessed again with a fresh workbook.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need a new _instance_ of Excel.  Each instance can open more than one workbook

Comment: ok, so I was mistaken. I only need one instance. how do i get the specific workbook named Grade_sheet to open?